# Tutorial On YouTube is using CInt While it does not exist

Tags: c#, scripting

Hello recently I decided to try to attempt to make something very small without using Unity. When I ran into a YouTube tutorial to change text into an integer for addition it said do

```
Dim firstNum As Integer = CInt(txtAddVal1.Text)
Dim secondNum As Integer = CInt(txtAddVal2.Text)
```

I was able to change a bit of the code from my previous experience to `int firstNumber =` My problem here is that I don't know how to convert this `CInt` into a variable that actually exists now. I am using Windows App Forms (.NET).

Comment: That tutorial you watched was VB.NET. You could use `int.Parse(txtAddVal1);`

Answer (score 3):

Code you have here is VB.NET not C#. `CInt()` from VB.NET can be replaced with `(int)variable` in C#

```
int firstNum = (int)txtAddVal1.Text
int secondNum = (int)txtAddVal2.Text
```

Other options are `int.Parse()` and `int.TryParse()`

https://www.dotnetperls.com/parse

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: Ohh and also how would I change an integer into a string?

Comment: Just by calling ToString() method on int variable.

Comment: if I have the Integer sum would I just write it as txtFinalAnswer.Text = ToString(sum);

Comment: txtFinalAnswer.Text = sum.ToString();